# Agregate cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is my database in Neo4j:

```
CREATE (Alex:Person {name:'Alex', phone:'0420965111'})
CREATE (Oxana:Person {name:'Oxana', email:'oxana@mail.com'})
CREATE (Tango:Dance {name:'Tango'})
CREATE (Ballet:Dance {name:'Ballet'})
CREATE (Zouk:Dance {name:'Zouk'})
CREATE (Saturday:Day {name:'Saturday'})
CREATE (Sunday:Day {name:'Sunday'})
CREATE (Wednesday:Day {name:'Wednesday'})
MERGE (Alex)-[:LIKES]->(Tango)
MERGE (Alex)-[:LIKES]->(Zouk)
MERGE (Oxana)-[:LIKES]->(Tango)
MERGE (Oxana)-[:LIKES]->(Ballet)
MERGE (Alex)-[:AVAILABLE_ON]->(Sunday)
MERGE (Alex)-[:AVAILABLE_ON]->(Wednesday)
MERGE (Oxana)-[:AVAILABLE_ON]->(Sunday)
MERGE (Oxana)-[:AVAILABLE_ON]->(Saturday)
```

[image]

I need a list of more than 1 person who likes the same dance and available on the same day. How to write a query which returns this?:
`"Sunday", "Tango", ["Alex","Oxana"]`

This almost works: `match (p:Person), (d:Dance), (day:Day) where (p)-[:LIKES]->(d) and (p)-[:AVAILABLE_ON]->(day) return day.name, d.name, collect(p.name), count(*)` But I don't know how to exclude records where count(*) is less than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WITH`:

```
match (p:Person), (d:Dance), (day:Day)
where (p)-[:LIKES]->(d) and (p)-[:AVAILABLE_ON]->(day)
with day.name as day, d.name as dance, collect(p.name) as names, count(*) as count
where count >= 2
return day, dance, names
```

From the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/):

> The WITH clause allows query parts to be chained together, piping the
>   results from one to be used as starting points or criteria in the
>   next.

Also, you can add a constraint (`WHERE` clause) to filter data.